# Strange difference between [Del] and [Shift][Del] in Windows Explorer

Tags: file, explorer, privileges

Previously I thought that the difference between pressing the <kbd>Del</kbd> key alone and the combination <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is that the former one puts the file to the recycle bin, and that's all of the differences.

But no, there is more: I changed the access rights to a file programmatically such that only `SYSTEM` can access it (OK, there is an inconsistency left: I am still the owner of that file). When I look at its properties, only `SYSTEM` is shown on the Security tab. When I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, Notepad is started and tries to open the file, and shows an Access Denied message. When I press <kbd>Del</kbd>, the Access Denied message is shown after a few seconds. But when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, the file gets deleted immediately.

Happens both in Windows XP and Windows 7.

How can that be explained?